# svn2git migration from a specific starting date

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I'm using svn2git to convert a large (7 years old) project from SVN to Git, but i want to convert only the last 3 years starting from (01-01-2014).

running command:

`svn2git $SVN_URL --revision {"2014-01-01 00:00"} --verbose --no-minimize-url --trunk=trunk --branches=branches --tags=tags --authors ~/.svn2git/authors`

output:

`command failed:
git svn fetch -r {2014-01-01}:HEAD`

Any thoughts? I would really appreciate any way of help.

Comment: Would getting the revision number equivalent to "3 years ago" help to use it instead?

Comment: @Edmundo yeah it worked by revision number, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `svn2git` tool you use is based on `git-svn`.

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist.

You can also easily tell the conversion that it should ignore anything until a specific revision. If you want to limit this because `git-svn` and thus the `svn2git` you used needs ages to complete, I'm happy to tell you, that you will need only a fraction of the time with the proper `svn2git` tool.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the `svn2git` you used) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: finally i switched to subgit tool its very fast than svn2git and its working fine. thanks for your answer

Comment: @vampire Is there any way to make it work on windows?

Comment: Sure, I used it on Windows for small conversion already too. But it is much slower, so better get some Linux to use it. For example through WSL, optimally WSLv2. :-)